# change jquery masonry css with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-masonry

I'm trying to dynamically change the css properties of a jquery masonry plugin box.

Essentially, I'm going to make the box expand, i've this code, but it yields no results.

```
$container.click(function(){
    var elem = document.getElementById($container);
    elem.style.width="500px";
});
```

I expect for the width of the block to change to 500px when I click on it, but it doesn't.

Any insight on dynamically changing css via javascript would be great.  Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't look to me as if `$container` is a string, which it must be if that `getElementById()` call is going to work.  Why are you using `getElementById()` anyway in jQuery code?

Comment: Well, I was trying to use some tutorials online. 

I started out with just $container.style.width, but that also didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is:

```
$(this).css('width', '500px');
```

in the "click" handler. (That's assuming that the "container" is the box whose size you want to change.)

Answer (score 1):

Change the handler internals to

```
   $container.css({width:"500px"});
```